# C++: Access violation writing location

Tags: c++, access-violation, unhandled-exception

Using: MSVS2012

**Code**

*elemalg.h*

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class ElemAlg
{
private:
std::string difficultlyLevel, question, answerToRead;
std::vector<std::string> questions, answers;

std::vector<std::string> GetQuiz(int);
};
```

*elemalg.cpp*

```
#include "elemalg.h"

std::vector<std::string> ElemAlg::GetQuiz(int difficulty)
{
if (difficulty == 1) { difficultyLevel = "algE"; }
if (difficulty == 2) { difficultyLevel = "algM"; }  
if (difficulty == 3) { difficultyLevel = "algH"; }
if (difficulty == 4) { difficultyLevel = "algVH"; }

std::ifstream fin(difficultyLevel + ".txt");
while (std::getline(fin, question)) { questions.push_back(question); }
fin.close();

std::ifstream fin2(difficultyLevel + "Answers.txt");
while (std::getline(fin2, answerToRead))    { answers.push_back(answerToRead); }
fin2.close();

return questions;
}
```

*MathTutor.cpp*

```
#includes etc
ElemAlg *ea;
ea->GetQuiz(1);
```

`GetQuiz` is definitely passed an integer between 1 and 4, this is verified before the method is called

`difficultyLevel` is a string defined in the header file.

The compiler throws an Unhandled exception and Access violation writing location ... as soon as it hits the first `if` function.

If I remove the `if` functions and define `difficultyLevel` as algE just for testing the same problem.

If I remove `difficultyLevel` entirely and just open the file as `"algE.txt"` and `"algEAnswers"` then I get the same problem but at a different memory location once the code hits the while loop.

Comment: What is `difficultyLevel` exactly?

Comment: The parameter should be verified inside the function with an assert and not outside. If questions is a global variable, I don't know why you try to return it.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen.

Comment: Your ElemAlg object is not valid. I think you need to send us the surrounding the code.

Comment: difficultyLevel is just a string used to determine which file to open. 
i.e. if the user has decided upon difficulty of 2 then the file "algM.txt" is opened

Comment: Please edit your question and show at least the exact types. If you say _"string"_, I suppose you actually mean a `std::string`?

Comment: added what I think is relevant to be added. Sorry for original incomplete question.

Comment: We need to COMPILE it ourselves or we are just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: If you have it like this: `ElemAlg *ea;
ea->GetQuiz(1);` that's blatantly wrong! Change to `ElemAlg ea;
ea.GetQuiz(1);`

Comment: @user3001499 - `If I remove the if functions and define difficultyLevel as algE just for testing the same problem`  You should stop removing code, and instead keep the original faulty code and learn why it is giving you an issue and fix it.  Removing code potentially may then hide the bug, giving you the false sense that you've fixed the problem "by magic".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ElemAlg *ea;
ea->GetQuiz(1);
```

You're not creating an instance of `ElemAlg`, so you're calling a member function on an uninitialized pointer.

Because the member function you are calling isn't virtual the compiler won't have to do any runtime lookup, which is why the call goes to `GetQuiz`. However, the `this` pointer will be garbage (as `ea` is uninitialized), so the moment you access a member variable (such as `difficultyLevel`) you'll have undefined behaviour. In your case the undefined behaviour leads to an access violation.

Either initialize `ea`:

```
ElemAlg *ea=new ElemAlg;
ea->GetQuiz(1)
```

or, if you don't need to allocate it on the heap just do:

```
ElemAlg ea;
ea.GetQuiz(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much...my program is different but it helped me to solve my problem... 
I just change the memory allocation statement with new keyword
Getting Same Error with statement : `MyQueue *newnode = (MyQueue*)malloc(sizeof(MyQueue));`
  
Change above statement to : `MyQueue *newnode = new MyQueue;`